# Select2 is not willing to work with Laravel 9 and Vite? Am I missing something?

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-9

I just fresh-installed a Laravel 9 app, added select2 and jquery with npm, passed what I needed to pass to vite.config.js and app.js, jquery is getting loaded way before select2 is loaded and yet still, select2 throws

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at select2.min.js:2:241
    at select2.min.js:2:249
```

I even made a div#test and used jquery to put "ok" inside it when the window is loaded, it changes to "ok", but then why is select2 complaining?

package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.6.1",
        "select2": "^4.1.0-rc.0"
    }
```

vite.config.json

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '$': 'jQuery',
        },
    },
});
```

app.js

```
import "./bootstrap";
import $ from "jquery";
window.$ = $;
// import { Select2 } from "select2"; // does nothing when uncommented
import 'select2'; // does nothing

$("#test").html("ok");

$(document).on("load",function() { // does nothing
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

index.blade.php

```
just partial paste
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="test"></div> <--- this will have "ok" in it since jquery is loaded

    <select class="js-example-basic-single"> <--- this displays as a regular select instead of select2
        <option value="x">asd</option>
        <option value="x">asd</option>
        <option value="x">asd</option>
        <option value="x">asd</option>
    </select>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js" defer></script> <------ if I have this "jquery is not defined" will be thrown
partial paste end
```

If I remove the CDN script from the end, it won't throw the error anymore but still won't work. Also CDN is only used while I test if it works or not, I'll need it locally anyway...

I literally tried everything I could, I've been struggling with it for 4 days and can't figure out what's wrong with this.

Comment: in your app.js, try to add `select2($);` below `import 'select2';`

Comment: Laravel works out of the box with vue.js. Why would you go out of your way to create a new project and use legacy jQuery instead? unless you have a real use case for having to use jQuery I would uninstall it and use the advised Laravel front end

Comment: The task I got includes it as a "must", so I must use it in the project, sadly. I know about Vue btw, looking forward to trying it!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I got it partly working by adding this to bootstrap.js:
`import select2 from 'select2';
select2();
$('.select2').select2();`
Now the only issue is that the css of select2 doesn't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After you install Select2 using: `npm install select2 --save-dev`, you need to add these 2 lines to bootstrap.js, after the jQuery import lines:

```
import select2 from 'select2';
select2();
```

Also add the Select2 CSS to app.scss:

```
@import "/node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.css";
```

Alternatively you can add the Select2 CSS to app.js

```
import "/node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.css";
```

In your JavaScript you can use it like you used to:

```
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It works with `npm run dev` but fails with `npm run build` with the error `'default' is not exported by node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js`

Answer (score 3):

After installing Select2 (and Jquery of course) with npm `npm install select2 --save-dev`, I had to initialize it.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import select2 from 'select2';
select2($);
```

After that, you can use it like you usually do, `$(`#mySelect`).select2();`

Also, in your other `<script>` tags, don't forget to add `type='module'`, otherwise they get loaded before Vite loads your app.js and Jquery's `$` is not yet defined.

Comment: There was already an answer about half a year ago.

Comment: Which didn't work for me so I had to adapt something else and gave it here for people to use :)

Comment: Oh I see. Strange it didn't work, maybe version difference?

Comment: Most probably it is yeah